# Language to record and edit webcam video

Tags: programming-languages, webcam

I was wondering what language people would suggest to use when attempting to create a program that can record the video feed for three different webcams and being able to splice out 5 or 10 seconds of the stream into a video file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Mandarin or Spanish according to the trending markets in global languages

Answer (score 1):

This is less of a "language choice" problem than an "environment choice" problem - any language that can be used to develop long-running processes that can interact with whatever webcam/image acquisition API will be appropriate.

- C#/VB.NET, Python, or C++ will be your best bets (in order of increasing difficulty).
- The task would be impossible in PHP, EcmaScript, VBScript, and Brainfuck.
- Java and Assembly are possibilities, but probably make things more difficult than they need to be.

We need more information about what kind of webcams they are (USB UVC class? Firewire DV or Firewire IIDC? Network webcams with their own Motion-JPEG servers built-in?) before we can offer specific advice.

Comment: Kudos for giving a reasonable answer to an extremely broad question.

Answer (score 0):

I did a project fairly painlessly using Adobe Flex to capture client webcam video and stream it to a server. It's  a good choice if you need to do this over the web. If your environment is more controlled, as in you're in control of all the hardware, I'd use Max/MSP/Jitter, which is easy to get wired up capturing video, and is designed to do realtime splicing and such.

And the benefit of either of these options is that you *don't* need to know ahead of time which hardware varieties are being employed, since either runtime has the handlers for any of these.